# Insert values into a database using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from a html table based on which check box is checked

```
function updtBask() {

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var chkBox = document.getElementById("1");
//for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i].cells[4]; i++) {
    if (chkBox.checked) {
        var imgOne = document.getElementById("mytable").rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
        var prcOne = document.getElementById("mytable").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
        var nameOne = document.getElementById("mytable").rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML;
        var descOne = document.getElementById("mytable").rows[1].cells[3].innerHTML;
    }
```

then send this data to a php file which then inserts these values into a database.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","updateBasket.php"+{imgOne :imgOne, prcOne: prcOne, nameOne: nameOne, descOne: descOne},true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

My php is as follows

```
<?php
//create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("csmysql.cs.cf.ac.uk", "c1427641", "adnog9","c1427641");
//get variables from javascript
$one = $_POST["imgOne"];
$two = $_POST["prcOne"];
$three =$_POST["nameOne"];
$four = $_POST["descOne"];

 // command to execute
 $command= "INSERT INTO basket (image, price, name, description) VALUES ('$one', '$two', '$three', '$four')"
//execute command
$result = mysqli_query($con, $command)

//close connection
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

I'm new to JavaScript so I may be completely wrong here.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What errors do you get or response? Also you should add some protection against SQL Injection. This code would be vulnerable.

Comment: It doesn't insert the values into the table that it should

Comment: That is not how you send  post data to the server with an XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Could you please explain how epascarello? I've looked around online and it seemed to follow the guidelines I'd seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post request is incorrect. You code should look more like this:

```
var id = "xyz";
var value = 123;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'updateBasket.php');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status==200) {
            alert("good");
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("userid=" + encodeURIComponent(id) + "&value=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
```

Comment: So using this with my variables thrown in, should work?

Comment: It's getting as far as the alert, I assume the fact that it's not inserting into the database is something to do with the next bit

Comment: If you see the `alert("good")` than the call made it to the server.

Comment: Must be my php then, I'll check over that now
If my .php file is in the same directory as the html, it should run shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks epascarello, worked out where the php was going wrong so it works fine now

Answer (score -1):

So what's the issue?  If you're wondering how to call `updtBask()` you can do so with a button:  `<button  onclick='updtBask()'>Update</button>`

Comment: I have a button which is calling it but for some reason, the data I want isn't being inserted into the database table

Comment: I think you're using xmlhttp correctly.  See here under 'post' http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Yeah that is what I was following but someone above said my use of POST was wrong